# Compilation app.js laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm having a problem with laravel 5.4 I'm trying to put a personal js library and I'm not getting it

I'm also not able to remove the vue.js

I think it's in the compilation of the lavender mix

my files

Package.json

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  }
}
```

assests/js/app.js

```js
 require('./bootstrap');
```

webpack.mix.js

```js
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');



 mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
 .js('resources/assets/js/cidades-estados-1-4.js', 'public/js');
```

I tried an npm update and then an npm run dev or prod but it does not update, it is still with the vue.js that I removed

My app.js is giant

Comment: Stackoverflow is an English only site, with non English parts of your question there is little chance you will get a proper answer

Comment: @milo526 thks, i edit that